# MySQL select not work correctly on fields contain accents

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, mariadb

Hi guys i have a problem with my DB, in detail i have this table:

```
CREATE TABLE `energy_vector` (
  `id` char(36) NOT NULL,
  `creation_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `modification_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `denomination` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aliases` longtext,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DEFAULT COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

This table contain some rows and in particular the problem is on these two rows:

```
INSERT INTO `energy_vector` (`id`, `creation_date`, `modification_date`, `denomination`, `aliases`) VALUES
('e4814054-5345-7ece-90aa-59e74b0008bb', '2017-10-18 14:38:44', '2017-11-15 15:17:10', 'Elettricità approvvigionata dalla rete elettrica', NULL),
('e59a4f52-8bba-734e-4a5e-59e74b464564', '2017-10-18 14:38:44', '2017-11-15 15:18:09', 'Elettricità prodotta da fonti rinnovabili', NULL);
```

Note that both rows contain a string with **accent** in the column `denomination`.
Now i execute these two queries:

**First**:

```
select * from energy_vector where denomination = 'Elettricità prodotta da fonti rinnovabili';
```

**Second**:

```
select * from energy_vector where denomination = 'Elettricità approvvigionata dalla rete elettrica';
```

First query return the row that i search and match correctly the string, but the Second query return me nothing. Why?

I checked a billions of time that the string is correct but i think it's a problem of the accent bound to charset or collation. Can anyone have a solution and explain me why? Thank you in advance.

---

*MySQL version: 10.0.31-MariaDB*

Comment: This is strange, because both strings should be covered by the same collation, and it it works for one, it should work for the other.  Are you certain that this behavior is reproducible?

Comment: Both queries work fine in my machine. I tried reproducing the problem. But it doesn't have any issue.

Comment: I just now try to duplicate the interested row with another id and the select return me only the new row but the rows with searched string are now two. It is possible that a row is dirty?

Comment: I tested it here and it's working http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=fe7016f75e395260095c864fa9c11ee1

Comment: Make sure you use the command-line client and not any other tools; run both queries from the same client session; if the problem is still repeatable, paste the output of `show variables like '%char%'`

Comment: Take `HEX()` of the column and of the string provided -- perhaps there is a tab instead of space or a spurious CR or LF.